# How can I be sure a daemon thread is always running, in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

In a web app my code creates some daemon threads as inner classes to check some information from incoming requests.

```
    private static class AlertThread extends Thread {

    private AlertThread() {
        setDaemon(true);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
               ...
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                LogFactory.getLog(AlertThread.class)
                        .warn("InterruptedException when waiting");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                mainLogger.error("Error processing Alert " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code works well, and thread is running fine, but I want to be sure that this thread will be always running, and if it is killed (by any unknown reason), how should I restart a new instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to not let it die in the first place. You can do this

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
          runOne();
        } catch(Throwable t) {
          // log t
        }
    }
}
```

This thread will not die unless you shutdown the application.

BTW You should make the thread a daemon before you start it and you should avoid extending Thread as doing so can lead to subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1):

As your code is written, the `while` loop could be terminated by any `Trowable` that is not an `Exception`. It could be an `Error` such as a `StackOverflowError` for example.

Comment: Or some crazy person could throw a `Throwable` or a sub-class which is not Error or Exception ;)